# Is it possible to add a custom page in Swagger?

Tags: swagger, nestjs, openapi

I am building a REST API with NestJS and I use the Swagger module to generate a documentation.

Swagger creates a one page documentation concerning all my routes. I would like to manually add a bit of documentation on top on the existing documentation. Is there any way I can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the @nestjs/swagger module, you can add a description that supports markdown with the `setDescription()` method on the `SwaggerBaseConfig` object (that is created with `new DocumentBuilder()`. You could have something that looks like

```
  const document = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('My Api')
    .addTag('My Tag', 'The description for it')
    .setBasePath('/api')
    .setDescription('Here is where you can add extra documentation that will' +
        ' show up above the generated swagger file. You can make it as long' +
        ' or as short as you would like. You technically don\'t need to wrap' +
        ' the string either, it just makes things easier to read.'
    );
```

A lot of great information on the module [can be found here](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swagger) and a great (though basic) example [can be seen on GitHub](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/tree/master/sample/11-swagger)